# add an ng-model to ng-click that passes true false params

Tags: angularjs

I basically have this button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isPrivate = !isPrivate">
                    {{isPrivate ? "Make Event Public" : "Make Event Private"}}
                </a>
```

I'm wanting to have it so the button once clicked passes true false to the controller. I've tried this

```
<a ng-model="event.public" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isPrivate = !isPrivate">
                    {{isPrivate ? "Make Event Public" : "Make Event Private"}}
                </a>
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Heres the code in the controller

`$scope.event.public = '';`

I've found out i can do it like this with a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="public" ng-click="isPrivate = !isPrivate" ng-model="event.public"
           ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

I'd prefer it being a button though rather than a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a ngModel for your button. You can just do

```
$scope.event = {
      public : true
    }
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DJ9RWSknAO8wwRyrXEzP?p=preview)

Comment: Hi there, Thats not working with my code, Pretty sure ive done everything right.